# If $\mu$ is finite and $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a set of pairwise non-equivalent atoms, then $\mu(\cup_{n}A_n)=\Sigma_{n}\mu(A_n)$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Firstly consider the following two definitions:

> **D1:** Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu )$ be a measure space. We say that $A\in \Sigma $ is an **atom** if $\mu (A)>0$ and, given any $B\in \Sigma $
> with $B\subseteq A$, $\mu (B)=\mu (A)$ if, and only if, $\mu (B)\neq 0$.
>
> **D2:** Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu )$ be a measure space. We say that $E,F\in \Sigma$ are **equivalent**, which we denote by $\color{red}{E\sim F}$,
> if $\mu(E\vartriangle F)=0$.

**My question:** is the following proposition true?

> **Proposition:** Let $(X,\Sigma ,\mu )$ be a measure space. If $\mu$ is finite and $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a collection of pairwise
> *non*-equivalent atoms, then $\mu (\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)=\Sigma _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu (A_n)$.

---

I was able to prove that proposition, however, since I didn't see that proposition being used anywhere, there's a possibility that my proof is flawed. Below is what I did:

Define $A'_0:=A_0$ and $A'_{n}:=A_n\setminus \bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}A_{k}$ for all natural $n\geq 1$.

It's easy to prove that $\{A'_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint atoms such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $A'_n\sim A_n$ and $\sqcup_{k=0}^n A'_k=\cup_{k=0}^nA_k$.

Then $\sqcup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A'_n=\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ and, since $ A'_n\sim A_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we can show that $\mu ( A'_n)=\mu (A_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore

$$\mu (\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)\leq \Sigma _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu (A_n)=\Sigma_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu ( A'_n)=\mu (\sqcup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A'_n)=\mu (\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)$$

We conclude from the previous inequality that $\mu (\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)=\Sigma _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu (A_n)$.

---

Thank you for your attention!